# Explain how this function works

Tags: javascript

```js
let a = () => {
  return ((b) => alert(b))("hello");
};

a();
```

This function alerts "hello", please explain to me how this works and what type of a function this is?

Comment: `((b) => alert(b))` - this is a function expression which is then immediately invoked using `()` and "hello" is passed as the argument to the function expression which is assigned to the parameter `b` inside the function expression.

Answer (score 4):

It's a function which, inside, calls an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) - i.e. a function that is declared and called in the same line.

The return does nothing (it returns the return value from the `alert()`, which is undefined; nothing is listening for the return.)

Both the outer function and the IIFE use what's called arrow functions - short-syntax functions that don't have their own `this` context.

The whole thing could be reduced to simply:

```
let a = () => alert('hello');
a();
```

Comment: or simply `alert('hello');`

Answer (score 3):

`(b) => alert(b)` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

`((b) => alert(b))` our arrow function is actually an [anonymous function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), and we need to wrap it between parentheses in order to invoke it in place

`((b) => alert(b))("hello")` we pass `"hello"` as an argument to our function when invoking it

`() => { return ... }` is yet another [anonymous arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), except this time, instead of invoking the function in place, we store in a variable named `a` so that we can invoke it later

`a()` calls the previously stored function, which in turn calls `(b) => alert(b)` with the argument `"hello"` which in turn calls `alert("hello")`

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on the

```
((b) => alert(b))("hello");
```

first. ((b) => alert(b)) is a function that take a parameter b, and return alert(b). And the ("hello") here, is a parameter that is send to this function.

Soo, about this whole expression. I can present another form that'll work

```
let a = () => {
    ((b) => alert(b)) ("hi")
}
a()
```

here you don't even have to have a return. Alert return nothing anyway. So basically, in this block, you define a function a, that take no parameters, and execute the code that i already explained.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

IIFE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Same as

```
let a = () => {
  return ((b) => alert(b))("hello");
};

a();
```

`a` is a named function `let a =`

`a` is an arrow function `() => {}`

`a` is a parameter-less arrow function since the parenthesis is empty `()`

`((b) => alert(b))("hello");` is an immediately invoked function since it is inside the `()`

`(b) => alert(b)` is an arrow function with parameter `b` that alerts the `b` value

`((b) => alert(b))("hello");` gets the value `"hello"` since the `("hello")` passes the immediately invoked function using that value as  the parameter value for `b`

So given all that, let's see some examples:

```js
let a = () => {
  return ((b) => alert(b))("hello");
};

a();

// same net effect
((b) => alert(b))("hellos");

// same net effect
alert("hellosa");


(function(x){alert(x)})("hello Me")

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

let af = function() {
  return ((b) => alert(b))("helloaf");
};

af();

let na = function(nb) {
  return ((b) => alert(b))(nb);
};

na("hellob");


let nab = function(nbb) {
  return function(bi){alert(bi);}(nbb);
};

nab("hellobb");



function nab2(nbb) {
  return function(bi){alert(bi);}(nbb);
};

nab2("hello2");

/* two functions */
function sayHi(bi){
  alert(bi);
}

function nab3(nbbn) {
  return sayHi(nbbn);
};

nab3("hello3");
```